# How can I send data packets into the network without using sockets?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt

I want to send data packets into the network bypassing the Linux network stack. I mean is there any way where I can interrupt the network card driver and place a frame in the network card buffer directly to send it in the network? I am a newbie in Linux Kernel hacking so any guideline on how I can get started will be very helpful.

Comment: Can you describe why you're trying to do this?  There might be a better way to solve this problem than trying to bypass the well-tested, well-debugged, and highly-documented interface that is specifically designed to send packets. :-)

Comment: Raw IP packets, or raw Ethernet packets?  Depending on how low in the protocol stack you need to go, you may be able to use raw sockets.  Off the top of my head I'm not sure if you can talk directly to an existing ethernet card driver from userspace, but you could unload the driver and replace it with a version modified to enable this.  Obviously all of this requires administrative access, typically including the raw sockets.

Comment: Yes, sure. Actually my task is to compare the performance between a program than sends data packets using sockets and the a program that can send packet without travelling the whole Linux Kernel stack I mean like I said by placing the packet directly into the network card buffer.

Comment: My impression is that the most common reason people play that game (at least going after latency) is if they are working on high frequency trading systems, so you might do some searching based on that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Raw IP packets and raw ethernet packets both use socket. So I can't use them. I've done some searching on high frequency trading systems but couldn't find anything helpful. Any specific link or tutorial?

Comment: I was searching for how to send data without sockets and found this question. I am also interested in how to do this but can't find an answer... @mushfek0001 did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off if you used some **virtual device** like [TAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP). You can easily hack a control interface into the TAP kernel module, via which you can then pass frames ready to be sent out to the driver. That approach can be compared to the performance of a regular socket application as the baseline. Since in the end the TAP device will "send" out egress frames via a character device, you can easily write a test application measuring performance and latency.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm gonna look into it.